# Engineer some features of harvmac package

Tags: fonts, formatting, margins, geometry, article

Is it possible (in a LaTex article document) to use simple commands like

```
\usepackage[width=16cm,height=24cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}\setstretch{1.2}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
```

to (approximately) engineer in a nice and simple way the corresponding results obtained by `Harvmac` Tex package? if so, how can we guess the appropriate values?

Comment: It's certainly *possible*, but given that the `harvmac` macros are very minimally documented, you'd really need to dig into the code to reproduce it.

Comment: @AlanMunn if you understand plain Tex, can you make a guess of how the above 4 lines should be modified?

Answer (score 2):

There's a package called [chet](https://ctan.org/pkg/chet) which gives you the features of harvmac without you having to learn the functioning of harvmac. All one needs is a know how of the article class!